# How to overcome EAST Text Detector slowness in Android app?

Tags: android, opencv, east-text-detector

Im working on an Android app that's basically detects text and recognizes it (OCR) from pictures taken by users.

Im using Opencv V4.3 and Tesseract V4, and because of the fact that most of the docs (opencv) are in C++ and python, i try to test things in python before implementing them in java - Android.

So for EAST it takes precisely 1.6 seconds to executes on pyhton but in Android app it takes a whole lot more (didnt calculated it yet).

I have been thinking of using either multithreding, or async task for parallel processing bounding boxes (executing time 1 sec in python) but due to im new to mobile app dev and computer vision :/, i wanted to do some researching/testing first and take advice from SOF community.
Thanks.

Code used in Python : https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/17/opencv-ocr-and-text-recognition-with-tesseract/

Code used in Java : https://gist.github.com/berak/788da80d1dd5bade3f878210f45d6742

Answer (score 2):

After a long search, finally i discovered TFLITE, then i thought about converting EAST Detector model to tflite format although it might a litle bit slower, but its a progress, refer to : [Converting EAST to TFLite](https://github.com/ml-gde/e2e-tflite-tutorials/issues/14)

Now i begin to consider training my own model for text detection, i'll keep this thread updated for others in the future.